# Can you create an array inside of a struct initialization?

Tags: c, struct

So I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Board {
    size_t size;
    char* board;
} Board;
```

I was wondering if it was possible to then do something like this, during initialization of the struct:

```
Board boardStruct = {
    solutionLength, 
    char emptyBoard[size]
};
```

Unfortunately, when I try to do it this way I get the compilation error:
`expected expression before 'char'`

Any ideas? I'm trying to avoid declaring the array outside of the struct initialization, but if that is the only option I guess that is the route I will have to go with.

Comment: Maybe something like solutionLength, malloc(size*sizeof(char))

Comment: You can make the array part of the structure or call malloc. You can't declare it in there.

Comment: @kingW3, `sizeof(char)` is by definition always 1, or the language you're using is not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Board {
    size_t size;
    char* board;
} Board;

int main()
{
  const int solutionLength = 3; /* or #define solutionLength 3 */

  Board boardStruct = {
    solutionLength, 
    malloc(solutionLength)
  };

  return 0;
}
```

---

or closer to your proposal :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Board {
    size_t size;
    char* board;
} Board;


int main()
{
  const int solutionLength = 3; /* or #define solutionLength 3 */
  char emptyBoard[solutionLength];

  Board boardStruct = {
    solutionLength, 
    emptyBoard
  };

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @IanLundberg I added an other solution closer to your proposal

Comment: Is it not possible to use compound literals here?

Answer (score 0):

@bruno's solution will work. Another thing you could try is to put the array within the Board struct. E.g:

```
typedef struct Board {
    size_t size;
    char board[size];
} Board;
```

Upside: Avoids a malloc/free for each Board.
Downside: Board is larger, so it costs more to copy it. Also, you must know how big the board is before your program runs.

Comment: Warning, in that solution the size cannot change from a _Board_ to an other, this is a restriction from the initial definition of _Board_